# Timer and List<string> in C#

Tags: c#

I need help with timer and List.

List consist of collection of string say 5 or 6 at a time. Now, I want to display string one on label1 and it should wait for 5s and then display string 2 on label1. I have timer control and I am specifying my code in timer_tick event.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] myStatus = myStatusCollection.ToArray();
        int length = myStatus.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            string _myStatus = myStatus[i];
            //label1.ResetText();
            MessageBox.Show("Twitter Status =" + _myStatus);
            //label1.Text = _myStatus;
            //label1.Visible = true;
        }

    }
```

I have specify, Elapse = true and interval = 5000 but still I am not able to display one string at a time. In fact,  I am getting last string only. I want to rotate the strings all time.

Can anyone help me.

Comment: MessageBox is an odd way to test inside a loop, replace the MessageBox with System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine and check the Output window of Visual Studio to see the results, this will not block the UI or wait for user input. How does it look like in this way?

Comment: yes indeed messagebox is not usefull in such case, it stops the program flow till it get any action from user. label1.Text=_myStatus; this will do it u can use this method as thread and sleep 5 seconds each loop and finish it. if u want to use timer like brandone's answer each tick is a separate loop(considered) use index and at the end don't forget to stop the timer>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it is doing just what you told it to. However, what you told it to do is not what you meant for it to do. Try this.

```
public class Form1 : Form {

    private string[] statuses = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" }; // Init with proper values somewhere
    private int index = 0;

    private void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        string status = statuses[index];

        index++;

        if (index == statuses.Length) { // If index = Array.Length means we're 
                                        // outside bounds of array
            index = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because you're looping through all the strings each time the timer event fires.

Store your index in a private variable and use that instead.

```
private int _index = 0;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] myStatus = myStatusCollection.ToArray();

    string _myStatus = myStatus[_index];
    //label1.ResetText();
    MessageBox.Show("Twitter Status =" + _myStatus);
    //label1.Text = _myStatus;
    //label1.Visible = true;

    if(_index == (myStatus.Length - 1))
       _index = 0;
    else
       _index++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to display string one by one at regular interval. One more thing, what if I want rotate all string once it is display.

Comment: you may exceed the range of array ! then why i need to get an array each tick but i only need one element. i think if u get the array before starting te timer this is better.

Comment: @RushabhShah, if you meant you want to start looping again, just set the index to 0 when you reach the end. Ahmed, you can guard against that with a few checks. As for getting the array once, it probably would be better, but since he hasn't specified where myStatusCollection is coming from, I've left it as is.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create an int outside of the Tick to hold your position. Make sure you reset it back to 0 when you restart the process.

```
int MyPosition = 0;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    string[] myStatus = myStatusCollection.ToArray(); 
    int length = myStatus.Length; 

    if((MyPosition + 1) > length)
    {
        //Index Out of Range
    }
    else
    {
        string _myStatus = myStatus[MyPosition];
        label1.Text = _myStatus 
    }

    MyPosition++;
}
```